How to make stage names dynamic in Jenkins declarative pipeline?
How can I customize stage names in the declarative Jenkins pipeline?
I have the following matrix and I want to add app name in stages:
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'appName'
                        values 'foo', 'bar'
                    }
                }

                stages {
                    stage('Prepare') {
                        steps {
                            script {
                             // ...
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stage('Build Image') {
                        steps {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

When I try to interpolate string I get:
14:45:57  WorkflowScript: 121: Expected string literal @ line 121, column 27.
14:45:57                         stage("Prepare ${appName}") {


Have you tried stage("Prepare - $appName")? Note the double quotation marks which are required for string interpolation.

@zett42 it does not work - see updated answer

There might be a better solution, but as a workaround you could create the stages dynamically in a script section, by calling the stage as a step: stage('Build') { steps { script { stage("Prepare ${appName}") { echo 'Example for a step' } } } }.

@zett42 sounds like an answer

I don't feel qualified to answer, because I haven't used Matrix plugin before. I did use stages as a step within a script block for being able to generate them dynamically, so I thought this might be helpful in your context. I don't like to promote such workarounds when I'm not sure if there is a better way though.

@zett42 I will give it a try, tbh if there is only one workaround, then it should be promoted as the answer - if something better appears, then you can re-evaluate your answer
